# Error when retrieving latitude and longitude

Tags: android, gps, android-virtual-device

here's my problem :

I tried this tutorial to have the longitude and latitude of the device :
http://www.androidhive.info/2012/07/android-gps-location-manager-tutorial/

It worked fine on my phone (API 17) but didn't work on an emulated phone (API 25) nor a emulated TV (API 24). I always get latitude 0.0 and longitude 0.0

```
 public Location getLocation() {
            try {
                locationManager = (LocationManager) mContext
                        .getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

                // getting GPS status
                isGPSEnabled = locationManager
                        .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

                // getting network status
                isNetworkEnabled = locationManager
                        .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

                if (!isGPSEnabled && !isNetworkEnabled) {
                    //if internet and gps doesn't work
                } else {
                    this.canGetLocation = true;
                    // First get location from Network Provider
                    if (isNetworkEnabled) {
                        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                                LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,
                                MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                                MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
                        Log.d("Network", "Network");
                        if (locationManager != null) {
                            location = locationManager
                                    .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
                            if (location != null) {
                                latitude = location.getLatitude();
                                longitude = location.getLongitude();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    // if GPS Enabled get lat/long using GPS Services
                        if (isGPSEnabled) {
                        if (location == null) {
                            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                                    LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
                                    MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                                    MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
                            Log.d("GPS Enabled", "GPS Enabled");
                            if (locationManager != null) {
                                location = locationManager
                                        .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
                                if (location != null) {
                                    latitude = location.getLatitude();
                                    longitude = location.getLongitude();
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return location;
        }
```

After some test, I found that here :

```
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                                LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,
                                MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                                MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
```

The code go in the catch.

Does anyone know why it works on my phone and not in the android emulated devices ?

Comment: Maybe the emulated devices don't have a GPS/ a lat or lon set? If you use an emulator from Android studio, you could try setting the lat and lon from the emulators extended controls (the 3 dots to the right of the emulator)

Comment: your emulator likely doesn't have google play services

Comment: @paul_hundal sorry for the late answer (internet crash...) my device have latitude and longitude, I tried the send button but didn't work. How can I know if my AVD have google play service ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer : I tried my code on an AVD API 22 and it works just fine so this code is good until API 23, then you must use another one.
If I find a working code I'll post it.

**EDIT**

The code is good it's just that in api >=23 you have to ask the user if you're using "dangerous permission"